# Problem with fluid simulation, cannot generate fluids through pipe

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, baking, fluid-simulation, blend-files

I have set up the scene and assigned inflow, domain and obstacle(pipe volume as a shell) and liquid not generating after complete bake

[image]